# Low disk space “apt/archives”

Tags: apt, disk-usage, move-partition

I am having the famous warning "low disk space" on my Linux Mint in `var/cache/apt/archive` directory, and I want a permanent solution ( aka not `apt-get autoclean` because the mentioned directory is not enough for all the packages so cleaning it doesn't solve the problem[image])

What are the possible solutions to this problem?

Also is there a way to solve the problem without using partitioning or copying data to live disks like ***making a directory in another partition where apt can use it in the future installs?***

[image]

- I tried to create another directory that has enough space needed and used the command `ln var/cache/apt/archive /home/new/directory` but didn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. What _exact_ error messages are you seeing? When do you see them? What is `../apt/archive`? Do you mean `/var/cache/apt/archives/`? What's wrong with `apt-get autoclean`? "*making a directory in a larger partition*": larger than what? What is your current setup? Please [edit] your question and add more details, including the output of `df -h` so we can understand how much space you have to play with.

Comment: You can always format and mount another partition on /var/cache/apt/archives.  or symlink it to a directory on a partition with more free space.  on my machines running zfs, i created dedicated datasets for .../apt/archives, with a recordsize of 1M instead of the default 128K.

Comment: @cas How to make apt use another directory to store the packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to move the directory to another partition and then create a symlink from the old location to the new.

You seem to have lots of space free on /home, so use that:

1. `apt-get clean`

   This step is optional, but highly recommended.  It will delete all of the downloaded .deb files currently in /var/cache/apt/archives.  If you don't want to delete them, that's fine but the third step (`mv`) will take a while - however long it takes to copy and delete the archives from one partition to another.
2. Make a convenient directory for the .deb archives:

   `mkdir -p /home/var/cache/apt/`

   You can put it anywhere you like under /home (or any other partition with lots of free space available) e.g. `/home/apt` will do, but it's useful and convenient to keep the same directory structure.
3. `mv /var/cache/apt/archives /home/var/cache/apt`
4. `ln -s /home/var/cache/apt/archives/ /var/cache/apt/`
5. That's it, done.

   The next time you use apt, apt-get, etc it will follow the symlink from /var/cache/apt/archives to /home/var/cache/apt/archives - all of the downloaded files will be stored there.

BTW, if you're still short of space on /, you might want to do the same thing with `/usr/share/doc` - mv and symlink it to, e.g., /home/usr/share/doc.

Comment: thank you so much,appreciated... I already did those steps before and it turned up that the shortage of storage was because snapshots of the system taken daily, since I was installing packages at the same time so I thought the symlink not working due to increasing of storage used! sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: yeah, deleting files from a fs with snapshots won't actually release the space while there are still snapshots containing those files.   Which means you should exclude .../cache/apt/archives from automatics snapshots (this is what i've done with my apt/archives zfs datasets on my systems).   There really isn't any good reason to snapshot them, they can always be re-downloaded from the net.

Comment: The snapshots weren't for the archives, it was for the whole system, anyways thankfully the problem is solved

Comment: I guess you're using btrfs?   in that case, make the apt archives directory be a separate sub-volume and exclude it from your auto snapshot script.  and exclude it from backups too, both are a waste of time and disk space for the apt archives.